# Static List of Objects in Python

Tags: python, list, pointers

In python, everything is a "reference." In a simple program, I have a class:

```
class Watch(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.variables = kwargs

    def set_variable(self, k, v):
        self.variables[k]=v

    def get_variable(self, k):
        return self.variables.get(k, None)

    def print_info(self):
        for k in self.variables:
            print k + ": " + str(self.variables[k])
```

If I do:

```
list = []
tmp = Watch()
tmp.set_variable('name','frank')
list.append(tmp)
tmp.set_variable('name','doug')
```

then

```
list[0].get_variable('name')
```

is "doug"

How do I store temporary variables is lists or arrays while maintaining the array after appending?

Edit: Similar to [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list), although I'm wondering more about the property of object storage in python. It seems like objects are treated as pointers, instead of just passing their contents. Can someone speak to that? For instance, in a language like C++ I could say

```
list[0]=tmp
```

and then i could alter tmp and list[0] would remain.

Comment: What did you expect? You updated tmp `name` to `doug` and that's what's returned

Comment: try: list.append(copy.copy(tmp))

Comment: Please don't create variables that overwrite builtin objects... It makes me die a little inside

Comment: In c++, if you add an object to a list of objects, and then change that object, it's position in the array is unchanged (unless, of course, you use a pointer). That's what I was expecting

Comment: @FranklinHarvey that's the difference between python's call by reference and c++'s call by value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to put a copy of `tmp` in your list in such a way that if you subsequently modify `tmp`, then the copy of `tmp` in the list stays the same?

If so, then you probably want to use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module:

```
list = []
tmp = Watch()
tmp.set_variable('name','frank')
list.append(copy.deepcopy(tmp))
tmp.set_variable('name','doug')
list[0].get_variable('name') # returns 'frank'
```

Comment: or assign directly without a tmp variable: `lst.append(Watch().set_variable('name', 'frank'))`

Comment: @Aaron I think that's probably the way it's intended to be used.